# Karatzas and Shreve problem 2.1.4

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In Karatzas and Shreve problem $2.1.4$ asks that if we have a stochastic process $X_t$ such that for every set of indices $t_0<\dots < t_n < \infty$ the variables $X_0, X_{t_0}-X_0, \dots, X_{t_n}-X_{t_{n-1}}$ are independent. Then $X_t-X_s$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}^X_s$ for $0\leq s < t<\infty$.

The solution is provided and based on the Dynkin system theorem. They construct for every finite set of indices $s_0< \dots < s_n=s $ we have $\sigma(X_0,X_{s_1},\dots, X_{s_n})$ and claim that the union of all the sets of this form are closed under finite intersections. I tried to show this claim but I can't figure it out.

My attempt:

I consider two sets of indices $s_0< \dots < s_n=s $ and $t_0< \dots < t_m=s $. So I want to claim that:
$$ \sigma(X_0,\dots, X_{s_n})\cap \sigma(X_0, \dots, X_{t_m}) = \sigma(X_0,X_{t_1},\dots, X_{t_m}, X_{s_1},\dots, X_{s_n})$$

The inclusion $\subseteq$ is clear. But I don't see how to do the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sigma(X_{0},\dots,X_{t_{m}},\dots,X_{s_{n}})$ contains both $\sigma(X_0,\dots, X_{s_n})$ and $\sigma(X_0, \dots, X_{t_m})$ so it's not likely your equality holds.

We want show the set $$\mathcal{C}=\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}, s_{0}=0\leq\dots \leq s_{n}=s}\sigma(X_{s_{0}},\dots,X_{s_{n}})$$

is closed under finite intersections.
Take $A_{i}\in\sigma(X_{0},\dots,X_{s_{n_{i}}})$ for $0\leq i \leq k$.  Because $\sigma(X_{0},\dots,X_{s_{n_{i}}},\dots X_{s_{n_{k}}})$  is a $\sigma$-field that makes $X_{{0}},\dots,X_{s_{i}}\dots, X_{s_{k}}$ measureable, it must contain $\sigma(X_{0},\dots,X_{s_{n_{i}}})$, the smallest $\sigma$-field that makes $X_{0},\dots,X_{s_{n_{i}}}$ measurable. So  $\sigma(X_{0},\dots,X_{s_{n_{i}}}) \subseteq \sigma(X_{0},\dots,X_{s_{n_{1}}},\dots X_{s_{n_{k}}})$ and $A_{i} \in \sigma(X_{0},\dots,X_{s_{n_{1}}},\dots X_{s_{n_{k}}})$. Because $\sigma(X_{0},\dots,X_{s_{n_{1}}},\dots X_{s_{n_{k}}})$ is a $\sigma$-field we have $\bigcap A_{i} \in \sigma(X_{0},\dots,X_{s_{n_{1}}},\dots X_{s_{n_{k}}})\subseteq \mathcal{C}$ as we wanted.